# Swap grid[X][Y] to grid[Y][X] in full file

Tags: regular-expression, search, substitute

In my file, I have many instances of `grid[X][Y]` where `X` and `Y` are variables. I would like to swap all instances to `grid[Y][X]` (preferably one by one so I can check them).

Examples (especially note the second example):

```
grid[row][col]
grid[row + 1][col]
```

Swap to:

```
grid[col][row]
grid[col][row + 1]
```

Note that `X`/`Y` are guarenteed to contain only A-Z, a-z, 1-9, + - (if that helps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want

`:%s/\[\(.\+\)\]\[\(.\+\)\]/[\2][\1]`

And yes, I guess all these toothpicks are really needed.

Comment: `\v` would eliminate _some_ of the escapes

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want

```
:%s/\v(\[.+\])(\[.+\])/\2\1/gc
    \v                         Very magic mode
      (\[.+\])                 First group of [...]
              (\[.+\])         Second group of [...]
                            g  Global flag - substitute every instance on each line
                             c Ask flag - ask before each occurence
```